# Login failed. Please contact the maker of this app and ask them to report issue #1118578 to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I create an application that share a post on facebook with easyfacebooksdkandroid. My app works very well when the facebook application is not installed in my device. If I install the facebook application my code doesn't work anymore and It throws the error "log in fail 1118578"
Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284709068314243

Answer (score 0):

They saying [here](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/284709068314243/) :

> "We do not support android:launchMode="singleInstance" due to
>   technical reasons, and the new SDK throws a diagnostic message that
>   should notify you when you try to login."

So you need to remove android:launchMode="singleInstance" from the manifest for  resolving the #1118578 issue.